# ObjectContext instance has been disposed, async method, ToListAsync(), SqlQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, boilerplate

I've seen other questions similar to this but none close enough to help me figure this out. I'm getting the error here in my repository:

```
return await Context.Database.SqlQuery<MemberField>(sqlstring).ToListAsync();
```

How do I fix this? It has worked before without any changes to code so I know all I have to do is keep the context alive. I tried doing this:

```
Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

but it didn't help. This is inside an ASP.NET boilerplate project.

Thanks!

in the constructor I have:

```
public MyRepository(IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>     dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider)
```

Then I have a AbpDbContext class:

```
public class MyDbContext : AbpDbContext{
public MyDbContext() : base("Default"){}

public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString){}
```

}

You can grab a template solution just like the project I'm trying to work with from here:  http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/

Update: ABP handles creating and disposing database connections so I don't have any code to show that does that.

Comment: How are you creating/disposing your context? Show that please.

Comment: in the constructor I have: 

    public MyRepository(IDbContextProvider<MyDbContext>     dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider)

Then I have a AbpDbContext class:

    public class MyDbContext : AbpDbContext{
public MyDbContext() : base("Default"){}

    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString){}
}

Comment: That latest edit does not help much and is not what DavidG asked for. You are showing your constructors but nothing about the life cycle for the context.

Comment: The issue arises because of delayed execution of the query - the query is not execyted until the .`To.ListAsync()` occurs by which time the SQLQuery method has executed and disposed it's connection. The "best" (and it's not very good IMO) solution I have seen for this is to NOT wrap your DB Context/connection in a using statement and just rely on the GC to clean up.

Comment: I would show more but I'm not sure there's anything to show? Have you worked with an asp.net boilerplate solution before? I think it handles all this stuff in the background, which is one thing I hate about it. I would rather write more lines of code and be able to see what's going on. I added a link to the place where I generated the template for the project. You can download it and see for yourself how it works. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working but handling the dbcontext in a using statement, inside the repository. This prevents the Abp frameworking from handling the dbcontext and disposing it too early. So it currently looks like this:

```
public List<MyObjs> GetObjs(){
    using(var db = new MyDbContext()){
        var query = from x in db.mytable
                    select x;
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```